# python tkinter gui issue with images and buttons

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a script that I am trying to design to initialize a GUI with a default image and a button. When the button is pressed, it calls the getRandomCard function and is meant to replace the current image with a random file (ex: 1c, 2s, 5d, etc.) They are GIF files of playing cards.

I am working on getting the first image (default placeholder) and the button to appear when I run the program. I am currently getting an empty window with no widgets inside of it. What part of code am I missing, or what is not written properly?

```
import random
from tkinter import *

class randomCards(object):
    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        suitlst = ["s", "h", "d", "c"]
        self.rank = random.randint(1,13)
        self.suit = random.choice(suitlst)
    def getRandomCard(self):
        fileString = "DECK/" + str(self.rank) + str(self.suit)
        userDisplay.imgLabel = Label(window, image = fileString).pack(side= "left")
        userDisplay.imgLabel.pack()

class userDisplay(Frame):
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.master = window
        window.title = "Random Images"
        self.imgLabel = Label(window, image = "DECK/b.gif")
        self.imgLabel.pack(side = "left")
        self.cardButton = Button(window, text = 'Show Random Card', command=lambda : randomCards.getRandomCard(self))
        self.cardButton.pack()

def main():
    root = Tk()
    interface = userDisplay(root)

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am working on getting the first image (default placeholder) and the button to appear when I run the program. I am currently getting an empty window with no widgets inside of it. What part of code am I missing, or what is not written properly?

You never call `pack`, `place`, or `grid` on the instance of `userDisplay`. Since it is an instance of `Frame`, it will only be visible once it has been added to the screen with one of those geometry managers.

Assuming that you want `userDisplay` to fill the entire window, add this inside of `main`:

```
interface.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

Comment: I added that and now it shows the button and a transparent space where the image would be. Assuming that the directory is right, am I also missing something to display the GIF file?

Comment: @BenRoux: the `image` option does not take a pathname. There are plenty of examples on the internet of how to use images with labels.